# useState is not properly working with axios.interceptors

Tags: reactjs

so here's my simple code and i tried many things. I tried even putting the axios interceptors in useEffect on mount but it's not working. For some reason the setError doesn't set my error value, even when i get error from the response interceptor. I don't see anything wrong with this code, the only things that bothers me is why setError in axios.response.use doesn't set the value of my error.

```
const [error, setError] = useState(null);

const reqInteceptor = axios.interceptors.request.use((req) => {
  setError(null);
  return req;
});
const resInteceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (res) => res,
  (err) => {
    console.log(err); // <------------ This shows, but it doesnt change the value of error
    setError(err);
  }
);

useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    // Cleanup
    axios.interceptors.request.eject(reqInteceptor);
    axios.interceptors.response.eject(resInteceptor);
  };
}, [reqInteceptor, resInteceptor]);

const dismissErrorHandler = () => {
  setError(null);
};

return (
  <>
    <Modal show={error} onClose={dismissErrorHandler}>
      {error ? error.message : null}
    </Modal>
    <WrappedComponent {...props} />
  </>
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added "promise" and it works.

```
const resInteceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (res) => res,
  (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    setError(err);
    return Promise.reject({ ...err });//    
  }
);
```

You can check this on [axios github page](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors):

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    // Any status code that lie within the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response data
    return response;
  }, function (error) {
    // Any status codes that falls outside the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
    // Do something with response error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

## Console.log is in the wrong place

If you want your error update to be visible (or any state change for that matter) you need to log in the root of your function. If you put it in a function the data gets "snapshotted" and will not be updated.

### For example

```
...
console.log(error);
return (
  <>
    <Modal show={error} onClose={dismissErrorHandler}>
      {error ? error.message : null}
    </Modal>
    <WrappedComponent {...props} />
  </>
);
```

The value of the state is visible only on the next render. Each update causes a new render.

Comment: Yea i tried that.. But the things is i put the console.log there just to check if it actually goes there when i get err. It does go there but when i print the error like u say it keeps logging null .. even tho up there i have it setError(err).. You get my point? It basically goes there but doesn't change the value of error why is that